# Generating a new column with corresponding values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet as follows:

```
Column A          Column B
12/01/17          
12/01/17          Pizza
12/01/17
03/02/17          Cake
03/02/17
04/05/17          
04/05/17          Rice
```

Each food corresponds to a single date, but some cells in the food column are empty.  I need to create a new column which has the proper food values for each row according to date.  It should look like this:

```
Column A          Column B          Column C
12/01/17                            Pizza
12/01/17          Pizza             Pizza
12/01/17                            Pizza
03/02/17          Cake              Cake
03/02/17                            Cake
04/05/17                            Rice
04/05/17          Rice              Rice
```

I am thinking a formula is the best way, but am struggling to come up with what it should look like.

Comment: If you can sort the data on column A ascending and then column B ascending, the formula becomes very simple (starting from C2, I think it would be `=IF(B2="",C1,B2)`).  If you can't sort it, I think you can do it with two columns (C2 would be `=IF(B2="",IF(A2=A1,C1,""),B2)` and D2 would be `=IF(C2="",D3,C2)`)

Answer (score 0):

1. Resort Columns("A:B") by "A:A", "B:B"
2. Make sure there is a blank row above the resorted table

   ```
    Column A      Column B   Column C
   1  
   2  3/2/2017    Cake       =IF(B2>"",B2,IF(A2=A1,C1,"x"))
   3  3/2/2017               =IF(B3>"",B3,IF(A3=A2,C2,"x"))
   4  4/5/2017    Rice         etc.
   5  4/5/2017 
   6  12/1/2017   Pizza
   7  12/1/2017    
   8  12/1/2017
   ```
3. Copy down the formula from "C2"; "x" in the formula is irrelevant